# Using $ in a password

Tags: shell-script, password

Lets assume that password of my server is `Abcd$1234`

I am trying to ftp a file from other server to my server using the following in shell script

```
ftp -inv (IP) << EOF
user Username Abcd$1234

"lines to ftp file"

bye
```

I am unable to ftp. I tried replacing password as `Abcd\$1234` and also `"Abcd\$1234"` but no use.

But I am able to login to my server without ftp (just to verify whether password is valid or not)

Can anyone please help. I want to use `$` in my password at any cost

Comment: I tried it. But its not working

Comment: You can use  `<<'EOF'` newline and close it with `'EOF'`

Comment: @val0x00ff, using `<<'EOF'`, you still use just `EOF` to close.

Comment: @glennjackman nice catch. I just edited the answer. The last `EOF` should indeed not contain single quotes.

Comment: I would advice against storing the password in plain-text in a script.

Comment: Does it work if you use `ftp` interactively or with other ftp clients like `lftp` or `filezilla`? What ftp client are you using, what ftp server implementation is the server using?

Comment: Instead of putting the password in the script, why not use a `.netrc` file?

Answer (score 1):

Here documents. 
`cat <<EOF` followed by several lines of text, followed by the literal string `EOF` on a new line, NOT indented. The portion between the EOFs is passed to the command as standard input. If 'EOF' is 'quoted', substitutions WON'T be done; otherwise they are. See <<- for the indented variety.

So..

```
    ftp -inv (IP) <<'EOF'
    user Username Abcd$1234

    "lines to ftp file"

    bye
   EOF
```

should work and will treat `$` as literal `$`. It will not reference it as being a variable.

Comment: I am still facing the same problem.

331 Password required for oracle.
530 Login incorrect.
Login failed.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
221 Goodbye.

Answer (score 0):

instead of here documents, try something like this:

```
    pw='Abcd$1234'

    exec 6>&1
    ftp -nvi >&6 2>&6 |&

    print -p open Server
    print -p user User $pw

    "lines to ftp file"

    print -p bye
```

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `&'